# How to avoid SQL injection in PostgreSQL using the EXPLAIN command?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-injection

As far as I know `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, ...)` does not accept query with parameters:

`EXPLAIN (ANALYZE) SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE name = $1` it will produce an error: `ERROR:  there is no parameter $1 at character 107`

So I cannot use parameter bind `db.Query(myquery, params...)`.

How can I safely run the `EXPLAIN` command with any parameter I want?  Do I need to get a package that sanitize sql strings? I am building a program that explain queries automatically by accepting user inputs.

Comment: Does the execution plan depend on the provided value though? Why cannot be just 1 instead of $1?

Comment: Also, I don't get what input you are talking about. A complete SQL query to analyze?

Comment: @YourCommonSense Yes, the execution plan will depend on the parameter value, unless PostgreSQL decides to use a *generic plan*, which only happens with statements whose plans are cached, and only after a couple of executions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best thing you can do is create a prepared statement:

```
PREPARE stmt(text) AS SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE name = $1;
```

Then you can

```
EXPLAIN EXECUTE stmt('some name');
```

to get the execution plan without having to interpolate the string in the statement. If you don't want to let the prepared statement exist until the end of the database session, you can `DEALLOCATE` it.

If you don't want the parameter value to be taken into account, you can use

```
EXPLAIN (GENERIC_PLAN) SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE name = $1;
```

This will get you the generic plan and is available from PostgreSQL v16 on.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and contribution to Postgres!

Comment: One more question: running the `EXPLAIN` this way will change the output of the plan, comparing to running the query without prepared statement?

Comment: No, the result should be the same.